# How can I use Chinese characters (or more generally, Unicode characters) as a macro name?

Tags: macros, unicode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.2}

\newcommand\神{\ruby{神}{かみ}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\神
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

How can I use Chinese characters (or more generally, Unicode characters) as a macro name?

I can use either `pdflatex` (preferred) or `xelatex` (the last resort).

Comment: Try `\@namedef` and/or `\@nameuse`...

Comment: @Werner: How to use them?

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 If `foobar` represents your desired macro name, you can define the macro with `\@namedef{foobar}{<macro contents>}` and `\@nameuse{foobar}` to call the macro.

Comment: with tex/pdftex, basically you can't. with xetex or luatex you can, so you need to say what engine you are using.

Comment: @ChrisS except that you can't really do that here as in order to implement the utf-8 using 8bit fonts the characters need to be active and defined to expand to _typesetting instructions_ so  can not be used in `\csname` (`\@namedef`/`\@nameuse`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand\神{\ruby{神}{かみ}}

\begin{document}
\神
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you're using LuaTeX or XeTeX as engines you surely can define `\神` to do that task. Of course you must remember to have a nonletter after `\神` or to change the category code of `神` to 12.

What happens with pdfTeX as engine? That `\newcommand` would give an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

because `\newcommand` can't define macros with parameter text not consisting of only  `#1`, `#1#2` and so on (see below).

Using `\def\神{...}` wouldn't help either: the input stream before tokenization would be the sequence of bytes

```
<5C><64><65><66><E7><A5><9E><7B>
```

that is, backslash, d, e, f , then the three bytes corresponding to the UTF-8 representation of `神` (U+795E) and the open brace. What follows is not important for the topic because when TeX sees the open brace it knows that the *parameter* text has ended.

What you're really defining is, in fact, a control symbol, because the byte `<E7>` has been given category code 13 (active). This control symbol *must* be followed by the bytes (characters, if you prefer) `<A5>` and `<9E>`.

This wouldn't have adverse consequences, so long as you define no other similar combinations. For example, if you also do

```
\def\祟{...}
```

(with U+795F) you'll have a problem: this would be a definition of the control symbol `\<E7>`, so it would override the previous definition and usage of `\神`.

The fact is that what the editor shows you as a single character is, for TeX, formed by three bytes (characters). You *might* change the category code of `<E7>`, `<A5>` and `<9E>` to 11, so allowing to form a control word, but this would make it impossible to type `神` and get the character, since `CJKutf8` relies on `<E7>` to be active.

---

You may instead define a wrapper, say

```
\newcommand\CJKnewcommand[2]{% #1 is a character, #2 the replacement text
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname CJK++\detokenize{#1}++\endcsname{#2}%
}
\protected\def\?#1?{\csname CJK++\detokenize{#1}++\endcsname}
```

so after

```
\CJKnewcommand{神}{\ruby{神}{かみ}}
```

you might use

```
\?神?
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.2}

\newcommand\CJKnewcommand[2]{% #1 is a character, #2 the replacement text
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname CJK++\detokenize{#1}++\endcsname{#2}%
}
\protected\def\?#1?{\csname CJK++\detokenize{#1}++\endcsname}


\CJKnewcommand{神}{\ruby{神}{かみ}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\?神?
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]