# Command naming convention different abc letters

Tags: macros, characters, letters, abc

Is it possible to define command name containing greek (and latin) letter with any type of *tex? (latex, latex...)

Eg: \μμμμ or \μinv

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191152/how-can-i-use-chinese-characters-or-more-generally-unicode-characters-as-a-ma (I suspect there are others - but surprisingly hard to find!)

Comment: Be careful, this is discouraged for a reason, it can lead to unexpected results, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423018/48973) for some details.

Comment: Also possibly relevant, but discouraging: [Cyrillic letters in command names with PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439543]

Answer (score 1):

Should work out of the box with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\μinv}{}{text}

\begin{document}
 \μinv
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX on the other hand is not really set up for this, and I wouldn't recommend it.